# How can I get video frames from Jitsi Meet Conference in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, jitsi, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

I want to modify the video streaming coming from Jitsi Meet in flutter for adding effects. And I also want to change the default conferencing view and show the frames in my own custom view. But I am unable to access the frame using the [library](https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet) provided by Jitsi. How can I get the frame from Jitsi. Or is there any way to get the streaming link and implement the service using WebRTC?

Comment: You can code to click a screenshot wheneve required

Comment: I don’t think it is a optimal way of doing the work. Moreover i want the actual frames. Screenshots will contain other items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such way to do that in flutter application as it is directly shows on the view. So you may have to depend on web application to do such processing.